# Why Spring Boot rejects GET request because the URL was not normalized?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication

I am trying to migrate a spring application to spring boot. While running the application on tomcat server I am getting the following error:

> The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.

I have tried adding the following beans in my entry point class to resolve the error.

```java
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ui/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);    
        return firewall;
    }

    @Bean
    public StrictHttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall defaultHttpFirewall() {
        return new DefaultHttpFirewall();
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }
```

Error log:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193) [spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) [spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) [spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

I expect my jsp page to load instead of throwing 'Whitelabel error'.

Comment: The second answer in the dupe will work for you and give you time to solve the invalid URL sent by the front-end, at which point you should remove the workaround to re-enable the firewall. But remove the other two firewall beans.

Answer (score 14):

Please check the URL request being sent by the client/browser.

Most probably the url has double slash somewhere in between e.g. http://localhost:8080/some//path/here

This is not allowed by spring boot due to security reasons.

Comment: No the URL doesn't have any double slash.

Comment: please share the url which is being formed to hit the api. (Both what is being formed from client, and the one that you are expecting to become)

Comment: but before deployment locally // was working and why it created the problem after deployment?